# Duration and Convexity

Tags: fixed-income, duration, convexity

I am searching to estimate the evolution of my portfolio duration following a yield increase/decrease.
Can i use the convexity?
I mean IR delta x (- convexity) = Duration delta

Is it correct?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Get it. Thanks for your help Sharad !

Comment: If your question has been answered, please accept the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use convexity although the formula you have is not quite correct. Think of the portfolio as a single bond with price $P(y)$, where $y$ is the yield of the portfolio (we're making the assumption that the duration hedging of the portfolio is based on a single risk variable, the yield to maturity of the portfolio). Then, we have the usual definitions for modified duration $D$ and convexity $C$:
$$
D = -\frac{1}{P}\frac{dP}{dy}
$$
$$
C = \frac{1}{P}\frac{d^2P}{dy^2}
$$
We can rewrite the expression for $C$ in terms of $D$:
$$
\begin{align}
C &= \frac{1}{P}\frac{d}{dy} \left[ \frac{dP}{dy} \right] \\
  &= \frac{1}{P}\frac{d}{dy} \left[ -PD \right] \\
  &= D^2 - \frac{dD}{dy}
\end{align}
$$
This suggests that for a given change in yield $\Delta y$, we can approximate the change in duration, $\Delta D$, by:
$$
\Delta D \approx (D^2 - C)\Delta y
$$

**Example.** Consider a default-free bond with a face of 100, a coupon of 6%, a yield of 5% and a term of 10 years. Assume annual compounding. Then, we can directly calculate $D = 7.52$ and $C = 72.17$. If yields increase by 25bps, then direct calculation shows the new duration $D' = 7.48$. On the other hand, using our formula above gives:
$$
\Delta D \approx (7.52^2 - 72.17)*(0.25/100) = -0.04
$$